# explode in sql like php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have a role system, each role has permession, some times there are cross permessions between roles. 
i need to display nodes under this role.
every node has it's last status.
status are saved in a table with mention to roles

```
|----------|      |-------|
|id        |      |id     |
|title     |      |name   |
|status_id |------|role_id|
|----------|      |-------|
```

i store info in role_id like 1, 2, 3
this mean that is status is belong to these three roles.
So how could i use and sql or php query to deal with this. 
in some cases i use explode. but it's not work in this case.
is there any hints to da that?
thanx

Comment: _i store info in role_id like 1, 2, 3_ -> please read about the 'first normal form' — it does have advantages :) it's only partly a joke.

Answer (score 4):

You can use mysql function find_in_set() but I think it would be better if you normalize your table in order to store atomic values.